# How can I tell whether an interrupted rm -r removed any files?

Tags: filesystems, rm

I installed sshfs a Linux box and then mounted my Mac home directory. In the middle of troubleshooting a configuration issue, I did an `ls -l` on the mount directory (as normal user), receiving:

```
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sl
```

I then ran `sudo rm -r` on that directory but pressed `Ctrl+C` to terminate it immediately before it (looks) like the command did anything. I notice no files missing but I want to be sure - is there a way I can somehow inspect the filesystem log on my Mac to see if any files were actually removed?

Comment: There is no "filesystem log" (unless you mean the HFS+ journal???). The best you can probably do is look at the modification times of the parent directories of the things that might have been removed. If the modification time is right around the time you did the `rm -r`, then chances are something got removed.

Comment: To clarify/rephrase: look at the modification time of the directory in which (to which) you applied the `rm` command _and all subdirectories beneath it_.  If `rm` started by deleting `a/b/c/f`, then only `a/b/c` would have been modified.